# Calculating the probability that "at least" 2 users participate

Tags: probability

I will need to calculate probabilities for a more complicated task, but to simplify it and explain it better, here I will give a simpler example. Let's say I have 4 users and I have estimated the probability score per each user (using logistic regression) that a user will post in the discussion forum (or not):

$p_1=0.34$

$p_2 = 0.67$

$p_3 = 0.12$

$p_4 = 0.95$

Based on these individual probabilities, I want to calculate the probability that at least 2 users will post in the discussion forum. Based on the help that I have received in other thread, I have ended up the following solution:

$$P(at\ least\ 2) = 1 - P(none) - P(exactly\ one)$$

in which, P(none) is equal to:

$P(none) =  (1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3)(1-p_4)$

and P(exactly one) is equal to:

$P(exactly\ one) = P(none) [p_1/(1-p_1) + p_2/(1-p_2) + p_3/(1-p_3) + p_4/(1-p_4)]$

In this solution, I understand the first two formulas, however I am not sure about the calculation of P(exactly one). I could not understand it and I do not know the formula is correct. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Let's take the case of only user 1 posting and others not posting. Then, this probability is $p_{1}(1-p_{2})(1-p_{3})(1-p_{4})$, which is same as $\dfrac{p_{1}}{1-p_{1}}\cdot P(\text{none})$. This is the first term on the right hand side of $P(\text{exactly one})$ equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(\text{exactly one})=p_1(1-p_2)(1-p_3)(1-p_4)+\cdots+(1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3)p_4$$ (it has $4$ terms)

You can also write that as: $$(1-p_1)(1-p_2)(1-p_3)(1-p_4)\times[p_1/(1-p_1)+\cdots+p_4/(1-p_4)]$$

Comment: Now I understand the logic better. Then, I think the formula was correct, right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes the formula is correct, Glad to help.

Comment: One thing, in the second formula, $p4(1−p4)$ should be $p4/(1−p4)$ , right?

Comment: That was indeed a typo. Repair now. Thanks.